# How to improve my algorithm to store data on the hard drive?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, algorithm, zip

I would like to handle too much text data, and then save it to hard drive in zip archives. The task is complicated by the fact that the treatment should occur multithreaded.

```
...
ZipSaver saver = new ZipSaver(10000); // 10000 - is the number of items when necessary to save the file to hard drive
Parallel.ForEach(source, item => {
    string workResult = ModifyItem(item);
    saver.AddItem(workResult);
});
```

Part of a class ZipSaver (uses the library Ionic ZipFile)

```
private ConcurrentQueue<ZipFile> _pool;
public void AddItem(string src){
    ZipFile currentZipFile;
    if(_pool.TryDequeue(out currentZipFile) == false){
        currentZipFile = InitNewZipFile(); // 
    }
    currentZipFile.AddEntry(path, src); // f the pool is not available archives, create a new one
    // if after an item is added to the archive, you have reached the maximum number of elements,
    // specified in the constructor, save this file to your hard drive,
    // else return the archive into a common pool
    if(currentZipFile.Enties.Count > _maxEntries){
        SaveZip(currentZipFile);
    }else{
        _pool.Enqueue(currentZipFile);
    }
}
```

Of course, I can play with the number of the maximum number of items in the archive, but this depends on the size of output file, that ideally, should be configured. Now many items of collection, which is processed in the cycle, creating many threads, practical, each of which has its "own" instance ZipFile that leads to the overflow of RAM. 
How to improve the mechanism of conservation? And sorry for my English =)

Comment: This is almost certainly I/O bound; adding additional threads may actually *slow it down.*  You should do some performance measurement first to see if you are already reaching the maximum possible throughput on your hard drive with a single thread.

Comment: @RobertHarvey The only thing done in parallel is `ModifyItem`, which appears to be CPU bound work.  All IO (that is shown) is already serialized, as one would hope.

Comment: @Servy: If he's I/O bound, my comment still applies (except for the "slowing down" part), regardless of which part is being parallelized.  Any attempt to parallelize CPU work on an I/O bound operation will almost certainly produce no improvement.

Comment: The question about the organization of the pool, rather than about save to hard drive

Comment: Looks to me like the SaveZip is blocking.  Do that IO on another thread so you can immediately start adding to the next.  But block the  next SaveZip until the prior SaveZip is done.  Maybe use a blocking collection with a max size.

Comment: Thread, that call SaveZip wait result. In time the ZipFile that saving now is not avaliable for another threads.

Comment: If the question is about the pool and not the save to hard drive then that is a poor title.

Comment: @Blam, BlockingCollection<T> its an interesting variant, but what will in the AddItem method if the collection is full?

Comment: Naming is one of my weak spots))

Comment: You can limit the size of the BlockingCollection or not.  Are you starting multiple instances of saver?  If so I don't think that is the best design.

Comment: No, there is a one instance of saver. I understand that if i limit the size of collection, i will win RAM, but i has no idea what to do then collection is full

Comment: If you put stuff in the collection faster than you take out the collection will fill up. When the collection is full you stop putting in. Parallel does not magically create more resources.

Comment: Have you profiled your code to determine how many different ZipFile instances are in the queue? Do you know how many threads are currently running at any time? Seems like you could limit the degree of parallelism easily enough to ensure that no more than 3 or 4 threads are running concurrently, which might very well solve your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about limiting the number of concurrent threads, which will limit the number of `ZipFile` instances you have in the queue. For example:

```
Parallel.ForEach(source, 
    new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 3 },
    item => 
    {
        string workResult = ModifyItem(item);
        saver.AddItem(workResult);
    });
```

It might also be that 10,000 items is too many. If the files you're adding are each 1 megabyte in size, then 10,000 of them is going to create a 10 gigabyte file. That's likely to make you run out of memory.

You need to limit the zip file by size rather than by number of files. I don't know if DotNetZip will let you see how many bytes are currently in the output buffer. If nothing else, you can estimate your compression ratio and use that to limit the size by counting up the uncompressed bytes. That is, if you expect a 50% compression ratio and you want to limit your output file sizes to 1 gigabyte, then you need to limit your total *input* to 2 gigabytes (i.e. `1 gb/0.5 = 2 gb`).

Would be best if you could see the current output size. I'm not familiar with DotNetZip, so I can't say if it has that capability.

Comment: Thanks for answer! Unfortunately, DotNetZip doesnt get current output size.

Comment: Your variant is realy resolve the problem, but i afraid that it will affect the perfomance of the overall program. For example, if in source 10000 items, now it works fine in "max speed", but it works bad with 1000000 (RAM problems). If i will limit 100 threads (for example), i will resolve my RAM problem, but is will not be "max speed"... However, your answer is the best =)